# Use of Raster Calculator in ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, modelbuilder, model

I have the following equation:

```
3000*(1-exp((-0.000664)*input raster))
```

I want to make a tool to use this equation on raster images. I want to do this with the Raster Calculator with the help of ModelBuilder. Can you please explain the procedure for making this tool?

Comment: What specific problem/s are you encountering?

Answer (score 1):

**Step one:** Make a model

**Step two:** Search for "Raster Calculator" in the [search window](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00660000007q000000) (usually on the left side of the ArcMap Window)

**Step three:** drag the tool into the model builder box

**Step four:** double-click the tool and input your equations

**Bonus:** Use the [Iterate](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002w00000063000000) function to loop through multiple rasters